# regular expression in R, reuse matched string in replacement

Tags: r, regex, replace, pattern-matching

I want to insert a `'0'` before the single digit month (e.g. 2020M6 to 2020M06) using regular expressions.
The one below correctly matches the string I need to replace (a single digit at the end of the string following a `'M'`, excluding `'M'`), but the replacement pattern `'0$0'` is interepreted literally in R; elsewhere (regeprep in matlab) I referenced the matched string, `'6'` in the example, by `'$0`'.

```
sub('(?<=M)([0-9]{1})$','0$0', c('2020M6','2020M10'), perl = T)
[1] "2020M0$0" "2020M10"
```

I cannot find how to reference and re-use matched strings in the replacement pattern.

PS: There are alternative ways to accomplish the task, but I need to use regular expressions.

Comment: The point is not that your "match" is wrong, it is correct, the *replacement* you used is wrong, the `$0` is a wrong backrefernce syntax, it must be `\\n` as is explained and demoed in my answer. And if there is no point trying to use `$0`, there is no need to complicate the pattern with lookbehind, all can be done with a mere TRE default regex engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use a backreference to the whole match in base R regex functions.

You can use

```
sub("(M)([0-9])$", "\\10\\2", x)
```

With TRE regex like here, you do not have to worry about a digit after a backreference, since only 9 backreferences starting with `1` till `9` are allowed in TRE regex patterns. What is of interest is that you may use `perl=TRUE` in the above line of code and it will yield the same results.

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/zb2QfY):

```r
x <-  c('2020M6','2020M10')
sub("(M)([0-9])$", "\\10\\2", x)
## => [1] "2020M06" "2020M10"
```

Also, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vfOXHv/1).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to capture the digit after 'M' and not 'M' itself, therefore :

```
sub('(?<=M)([0-9]{1})$','0\\1', c('2020M6','2020M10'), perl = T)
```

Captured strings can be reused with \\1, \\2 etc, by the way.